# Add literal space character to pictured numeric output

Tags: string-formatting, forth

After about several hours of trial and error, I couldn't figure how to do it... Here's the code I'm working on:

```
: format
    ( n ds -- )
    >r            cr .s
    dup              cr .s
    >r               cr .s
    abs              cr .s
    s>d              cr .s
    <# [char] bl hold #s r> sign #> cr .s
    r@               cr .s
    dup              cr .s
    c@               cr .s
    dup >r           cr .s
    chars +          cr .s
    char+            cr .s
    swap             cr .s 
    dup              cr .s
    >r               cr .s
    cmove            cr .s
    r> r> +          cr .s
    r>               cr .s
    c!
;
```

As an aside... isn't there an easier way to have printed output, something similar to `printf` would be great. Another possibility would be to specify space character as the *first* character of a `s"   "` kind of string.

**EDIT:**

I found that I can do: `s\" \040 test"` in Gforth (though the manual says it's not standard). And `s\" \x20 test"` which is probably standard, but I don't quite understand where the part of the sentence which says whether it is standard or not relates. Still, I'd be happy to know how to combine it with pictured number output.

**EDIT2**

This is how I'd expect it be used:

```
create test 256 allot
s" prefix " test place
123 test format
s" suffix" test place+
test count type \ prefix 123 suffix
```

Comment: It's not very clear what your code is trying to achieve, so I am not sure how to help. Could you either explain your intent or comment the code? Preferably both.

Comment: @sheepez I'm trying to have a word, I'd call with a number and a pointer to a string allocated on the heap, then would have this number printed into the given string after the last character in it, growing the string's length to account for the number of characters added. The part I can't get done is the part where I want to append a whitespace character after the number printed to the string. I've also appended some code to the question to illustrate the usage.

Comment: What problem or error are you encountering? Is `format` running and just not doing what you expected?

Comment: @sheepez it doesn't print the space, it understands `bl` as if it was literal character `b` with whatever follows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for this example you don't need to add the space within the `<# #>` stuff. You can define strings with leading or trailing spaces with `s"`.

So if you start with

```
\ Push addresses and lengths for the prefix and the number
s" prefix "         \                             -- addr  u
123 s>d <# #s #>    \                      addr u -- addr u addr2 u2
```

The word that you want is something that concatenates them, for example:

```
: concatenate
    \ Moves the string addr2 u2 to the end of the string addr u
    >r >r                \        addr u addr2 u2 -- addr u
    dup >r over r> + r>  \                 addr u -- addr u addr+u addr2
    swap r@              \                 addr u -- addr u addr2 addr+u u2
    cmove r> + ;         \ addr u addr2 addr+u u2 -- addr u+u2
```

So if you call this and output the resulting string like this:

```
concatenate type
```

The output will be "prefix 123"

You could then apply the same word to the strings "prefix 123" and " suffix".

This doesn't use exactly the same memory locations as your example but it could be adapted, and just was the easiest way that I could demonstrate it.

---

In response to the comment, you seem to be pretty close to embedding characters in pictured output, I think you just need to remove the `[char]` e.g.

```
123 s>d <# # bl hold # bl hold # #>
```

Should generate a string like "1 2 3"

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no. I really wanted to know how to have space in whatever is being generated by `<# #>`. Probably a different example will help. How would I print `1 000 000`, if my input is a number 1000000?

Comment: @wvxvw I have added an addendum that I think is closer to the point.